# Use numpy.einsum to calculate the covariance matrix of data

Tags: python, numpy, covariance, numpy-einsum

My aim is to calculate the covariance matrix of a set of data using `numpy.einsum`.  Take for instance

```py
example_data = np.array([0.2, 0.3], [0.1, 0.2]])
```

The following is code I tried:

```py
import numpy as np

d = example_data[0].shape[1]
mu = np.mean(example_data, axis=0)
data = np.reshape(example_data,(len(example_data),d,1))
mu = np.tile(mu,len(example_data))
mu = np.reshape(mu,(len(example_data),d,1))
d_to_mean = data-mu 

covariance_matrix = np.einsum('ijk,kji->ij', d_to_mean, np.transpose(d_to_mean)) 
#I don't know how to set the subscripts correctly
```

Any suggestions how to make this approach workable are appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the definition of a [covariance matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_matrix), the task can be solved quite easily with

```
tmp = np.random.rand(5,3) # 5 corresponds to 5 observations, 3 corresponds to 3 variables
tmp_mean = np.mean(tmp,axis=0)[:,None]
tmp_centered = tmp.T - tmp_mean
cov = (tmp_centered @ tmp_centered.T) / (5-1)
```

If you need `einsum` anyway

```
cov_ein = np.einsum('ij,jk->ik',tmp_centered,tmp_centered.T) / (5-1)
```

Comment: What is ```(5-1)```/ where is this coming from?

Comment: @Pazu You need to divide `(n-1)` in which `n` is the number of observations, in order to compute the expectation of a matrix.

Answer (score 1):

You can avoid the matrix transposes in the other answer with the following:

```
N, D = (5, 3)
tmp = np.random.rand(N, D)
tmp_centered = tmp - np.mean(tmp, axis=0)
cov = np.einsum('ji,jk->ik', tmp_centered , tmp_centered) / (N-1)
```